# Convert content from excel cells from string duration to number of minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Excel file with cells content like 
**6h 18 m**
I.e. this cells contain duration values. 
I need to add new column to this spreadsheet where I will use values from exisitng ones in minutes.

For example: 
cell A1 = 6h 18 m
I want to add new cell with formula like

```
= convertToMinutes(A1) + 5
```

Can anybody halp me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [*Sum an "Hours and Minutes" Time Column in Excel*](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2010/01/03/sum-an-hours-and-minutes-time-column-in-excel.htm) for a vba macro that (almost) does that. the macro assumes the duration to be in `6 hr 18 min` format instead of `6h 18 m`, so you have to adapt it a little. shouldn't be too hard, though. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To convert to minutes you just do Cell*24*60 and you have minutes.  I think you'd need to remove the h from the cell content.

As above, to have a function, you'll need to write it in VBA.